# Should I ever use @Transactional on a Service class

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-jdbc, spring-transactions

I have a web application that uses Spring `NamedJDBCTemplate`, and all the calls to database are select statements.

In this case should i use `@Transactional` in my service class that calls the DAO class that inturn fires select statements to DB.

According to [Transaction statergies](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-ts1/index.html) listing 10 suggests to not use `@Transactional` for reads. Will i be bringing an overhead by using `@Transactional` and also i dont want to miss the AOP advises that i can bring in for `@Transactional` in future.

Comment: Vishnu: as far as I know select statements are not transactional at db level, you don't require @Transactional annotation that to be in your service layer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should always access the database from inside a transaction. Not doing it will in fact create a transaction for every select statements.

Transactions aren't just useful for atomicity of updates. They also provide isolation guarantees. For example, (depending on the isolation level) reading the same row twice in a single transaction can return you the same data, and thus make sure you don't have incoherences in the read data. Doing it with multiple transactions won't provide any such guarantee.

Comment: Thanks for your answere, I just want to compare weigh the pro's and con's of relying on the default transaction management v/s the "@Transactional". Am i just carring un-necessary burden by introducing the "@Transactional".

Comment: No. Using a transaction shouldn't make your code any slower.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to use @Transactional and set it as Supported not Required for such service
in this way if your service call outside a transaction it will not start a Transaction and if it calls from other service that is Transactional and already start a transaction it will participate in that transaction.

for example think that one service required to call two services in first one some data will inserted or updated and other one is just a select that return those data if these two service don't participate in single transaction the second service will not return data because the transaction start in calling service not committed yet .